# Converting string of lists of timestamps to lists of timestamps in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I parsed data from s3 which is similar to this

```
ID   departure
1    "[Timestamp('2021-05-25 09:00:00'), datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 25, 9, 21, 35, 769406)]"
2    "[Timestamp('2021-05-25 08:00:00'), datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 25, 11, 15), datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 25, 14, 15)]"
```

Is there any way to convert the `departure` into list

I tried this

```
samp['departure'] = samp['departure'].apply(lambda x: eval(x))
-> Error: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
```

and

```
samp['departure'] = samp['departure'].apply(lambda x: x[1:-1].split(','))
# Here datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 25, 11, 15) splited into many sub-parts
```

and

```
samp.departure = samp.departure.apply(ast.literal_eval)
error -> malformed node or string: ["Timestamp('2021-05-25 09:00:00')", ' datetime.datetime(2021', ' 5', ' 25', ' 9', ' 21', ' 35', ' 769406)']
```

Output should be

```
ID   departure
1    [Timestamp('2021-05-25 09:00:00'), datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 25, 9, 21, 35, 769406)]
2    [Timestamp('2021-05-25 08:00:00'), datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 25, 11, 15), datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 25, 14, 15)]
```

(I tried converters while `read_csv` initially but getting an error too)

Comment: What's ```x``` in ```samp['departure'] = samp['departure'].apply(lambda x: eval(x))```? That seems to be string but apparently error says otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to replace `"` present in your departure column:

Try via `replace()`:

```
samp['departure']=samp['departure'].replace('"','',regex=True)
```

**OR**

try via `strip()`:

```
samp['departure']=samp['departure'].str.strip('"')
```

If you are evaluating the values inside:

```
from pandas import Timestamp
import datetime
samp['departure']=samp['departure'].astype(str).apply(pd.eval)
```

**OR**

```
from pandas import Timestamp
import datetime
import ast
samp.departure = samp.departure.astype(str).apply(ast.literal_eval)
```